# Exception: Unexpected error while getting the method or property executeQuery on object Jdbc.JdbcStatement

Tags: google-apps-script, google-workspace

I used same Google apps script code to connect and query to my Oracle dabtbase for 2 years.

```
  try {
    conn = Jdbc.getConnection(url, username, password);
    stmt = conn.createStatement();
    results = stmt.executeQuery(query);
  } catch (e) {
    Logger.log(e.stack);
    throw e.message;
  }
```

And I ran a script successfully everyday for 2 years.

Then I tried to run same script (I didn't change anything) but i got error 'Exception: Unexpected error while getting the method or property executeQuery on object Jdbc.JdbcStatement' since last week.

And these problem does not happened continuously, pops up from time to time

stack error message

`Exception: Unexpected error while getting the method or property executeQuery on object Jdbc.JdbcStatement at myFunction (Code:149:20) at __GS_INTERNAL_top_function_call__.gs:1:8`

Comment: Same issue with Google apps